# Why is my Wordpress plugin trying to update as someone else's?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I'm writing a plugin, based on someone else's tutorial.. I've been changing parts of it as I'm building it, such as the name, names of functions and so forth. The basics of the plugin work as expected, and it shows up in the plugin manager UI. However, when I activate it, it shows my custom metadata (plugin name, version, etc), but it INCORRECTLY displays and "Update this plugin" message of someone else's plugin. Now this plugin appears not to be related to the tutorial maker (which was my first suspicion).. it seems not to be directly related to the plugin name, folder name, or filenames.. but I really can't seem to control it – other than remove the whole metadata section, which seems illogical.

What is linking my plugin to someone else's plugin, or otherwise causing it to wrongly identify?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin section gathers info from their online repo, so if you have named it to something that's already there, it will pull through that data.

Just give it a unique name:

```
/*
Plugin Name:  My Unique Plugin
*/
```

Comment: Ah.. yes you are correct. During my testing I was getting strange results for some reason – it was persisting even when I changed the name. Not sure why, but it has gone away now. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, please accept this answer if it has helped you :)

Comment: I had to wait.. you answered it too quickly :-)

Comment: You know what.. the bug has returned. I am using unique names, which are getting picked up in the backend, but it's being misidentified as someone else's plugin. I can change the name to anything and it identifies as the same incorrect plugin. Have tried deactivating. Yet literally the same name some time ago was working correctly. Seems like it's out of sync.. or once it misidentifies once it gets stuck. Maybe it is a real bug :-[

Comment: If it is a bug, it seems to go away if you change the version number of your plugin.. once the "Update" message has gone away you can rename to anything.